# Turning array specified string into array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this spit out from my data acquisition:

```
data = "[[[array([-9.99999773e-01,  6.74083498e-04]), array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04])], [array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04]), array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04])]]]"
```

the type of data is string, as I tested.

Is there any way to turn this into array form? For example:

```
data = [[[np.array([-9.99999773e-01,  6.74083498e-04]), np.array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04])], [np.array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04]), np.array([ 9.99999773e-01, -6.74083498e-04])]]]
```

This worked for my further analysis using python.

Comment: How did you acquire this data? It is not in a standard format that can be parsed into a python object easily. Is it possible to obtain it as the actual objects or in a different format, such as JSON?

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
exec("data = " + data.replace("array","np.array"))
```

basically you replace array with np.array and then execute the resulting string as python code

Comment: We should probably mention that this should be avoided in the case of user-provided data since it allows for the execution of arbitrary code.